# Short story about a robot army that fights a war against Satan's army and is lifted into heaven by God

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

I read a short story once where the End Times come and the leaders of the world decide to send their robot armies to fight Satan's army. The robots suffer heavy losses but are victorious. The humans begin to celebrate, but it's cut short when God ascends the warriors who fought for Him into Heaven, the robots!  Does anyone know the author and title?

Comment: We're going to need some more details such as when and where you read the short story. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in anything else

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was in a book of Best of Sci Fi Short Stories by year, maybe under the Asimov brand?  Could have been around 2000 or 2005?

Comment: This is probably a Robert Sheckley called (I think!) The Battle , or The Hour of Battle. I possibly have two stories confused in my memory

Comment: You are right about The Battle. The Hour of Battle is a different Sheckley story about telepathic aliens.

Answer (score 11):

Came back to post and I see that @Danny3414 has mentioned the answer in a comment :(

Well, it's Robert Sheckley's "[The Battle](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58544)". I read it in the Pournelle anthology [There Will Be War](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?88732).

It ends:

> But by then it was too late, for Armageddon was over, and the robots
> gone, and the Lord departed.

Comment: Dang it, you beat me to it.